# Filling an array from a datatable

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datatable

I have this code so far:

```
Dim arrayOfResults As UInteger()
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim r As DataRow

For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1


Next
```

I don't know what to put inside the for loop, I need to access the first column of the datatable for each row and store that into the array. So would it be something like this?

```
for loop

    arrayOfResults.? = dt.Rows(i)("Mat")
next
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need to transfer the values from the datatable in the array. A datatable is a kind of glorified array

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I need to transfer them becuase I have a sql statement that fills a datatable then I need to store every value in a certain column into an array and pass the array into a unit test

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = '...
Dim arrayOfResults As UInteger(dt.Rows.Count - 1)

For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    arrayOfResults(i) = CUInt(dt.Rows(i)("Mat"))
Next
```

Or:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = '...
Dim arrayOfResults() As UInteger = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) CUInt(r("Mat"))).ToArray()
```

Or:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = '...
Dim results As New List(Of UInteger)(dt.Rows.Count)
For Each row As IDataRecord In dt
    results.Add(CUInt(row("Mat")))
Next row
```

Answer (score 1):

There are substantially better ways to do this (especially LINQ), but to keep it closest to what you were doing, I would either use a generic list rather than an array (Like This):

```
Dim ArrayOfResults as New List(Of UInteger)

....

For i = 0 to dt.Rows.Count - 1
   ArrayOfResults.Add(dt.Rows(i)("Mat")
Next
```

Or you'd have to ReDim the Array after you know how many rows you have in your DataTable and then you could do somethign like:

```
For i = 0 to dt.Rows.Count - 1
  ArrayOfResult(i) = dt.Rows(i)("Mat")
Next
```

But, as I said, an array would have to be properly dimensioned first

Hope this helps at least a bit...

Comment: The items in a row are of type object they have to cast first to add them to other collections of specific types.